# Executable Built with PyInstaller Not Working – Camera Access in Python Application

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have created a Python application that uses OpenCV and MediaPipe to analyze push-up form via webcam. It works perfectly when run as a Python script. However, after converting the script to an executable with PyInstaller, the camera does not activate, and the program doesn't function as expected.

`pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole --add-data "<data_path>;." --add-binary "<binary_path>;." main.py`
(Note: Replace <data_path> and <binary_path> with the actual paths you're using.)

Symptoms:
The executable is generated without errors, and I find it under dist/main/main.exe.
When I run the executable, there's no error message, but the camera does not start, and the application does not function as it does when run via the Python script.
There are no messages in the console, and running as administrator does not resolve the issue.

Question:
What could be causing the executable to fail, specifically regarding the camera access that works when the script is run in the Python environment? Are there any additional steps I should take to debug this issue or specific logs I should look for?

Any advice or insight would be greatly appreciated!

What I've tried:

- Ensuring all necessary data files and binaries are included with the --add-data and --add-binary options.
- Running the executable on the same machine where it was built to avoid compatibility issues.
- Disabling antivirus software to check if the executable is being blocked.
- Checking the paths in the script to ensure they are relative and correct.

Comment: this is an interesting question. Are you able to debug (with log or print statements) where the code runs until (in the exe) ?